Gstreamer pipeline issue, can't access camera on Raspberry Pi
I have been trying to do something with image tracking, and have found that this simple line of code completely throws my whole program off because when I am in a new .py file, and run these two lines:
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

(the camera is working, functional, recognized by the device and I have picamera2 library installed if needed)
I get this warning message, and no live feed appears:
[ WARN:0@0.196] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (2401) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Failed to allocate required memory.
[ WARN:0@0.196] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1356) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0@0.196] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created

I am on opencv 4.6.0 and according to the build in my VideoI/O Gstreamer is YES (1.22.0).
I am expecting a live feed (rather, an array of images to track) so I can put it into this code:
import cv2
from tracker import *

# Create tracker object
tracker = EuclideanDistTracker()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Object detection from Stable camera
object_detector = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=100, varThreshold=40)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = frame.shape

    # Extract Region of interest
    roi = frame[340: 720,500: 800]

    # 1. Object Detection
    mask = object_detector.apply(roi)
    _, mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    detections = []
    for cnt in contours:
        # Calculate area and remove small elements
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > 100:
            #cv2.drawContours(roi, [cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)


            detections.append([x, y, w, h])

    # 2. Object Tracking
    boxes_ids = tracker.update(detections)
    for box_id in boxes_ids:
        x, y, w, h, id = box_id
        cv2.putText(roi, str(id), (x, y - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(roi, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

    cv2.imshow("roi", roi)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)

    key = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


I am very inexperienced with python and coding, but I got this code from a tutorial but instead of a "0" in the videocapture function, it was a .mp4 file.
I saw elsewhere that someone did this same thing as me and it worked for them with the "0" in the videocapture function.
What am I doing wrong? How can i make the Gstreamer pipeline so that my project will work?

it's always the same issue, every day, ever since someone decided that those pi cameras shouldn't use V4L2 but something custom. that's the whole issue. no, neither opencv nor gstreamer know of this libcamera or libcamera2. yes you need to use that library, because those pi cams don't want to support V4L2 for some reason. yes, that means you can't use gstreamer or opencv to access the camera.

there ought to be a canonical question on this by now... but I don't watch the RPI space. I'm only here because you tagged opencv.
